# Issue with building HIDAPI on mac

Tags: c, macos, hidapi

I'm trying to use the HIDAPI lib to aid in building some hid drivers for mac. Following the readme I'm told to go into the mac directory and run the make command. This unfortunately does not do much and I don't see in the readme any of the commands that I need to run along with the make.

I'm not interested in using the TestGUI right now, so if I understand the documentation correctly I should not need to install the fox-toolkit and run the make command with it.

Anyone know if there is a step here that I am missing?

Comment: Please post some output from the `make` command.

Comment: @Preston so I got it to build but I want to manually add the hidapi lib to an existing project. I'm not seeing the header file though after running the make command in the mac directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand the question is 3 years old, but today I ran into the same misunderstanding of the included readme file.

The solution to build the library on **mac** is to run (in the **mac** folder, using **Terminal**) the following:

> make -f Makefile-manual

This will build the lib and you can then test the results by running the test program included:

> ./hidtest

The results should be similar to:

```
Device Found
  type: 05ac 025a
  path: IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/XHC1@14000000/HS05@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14400000/Touchpad@1/AppleUSBMultitouchDriver@14400000,1
  serial_number: 
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Product:      Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
  Release:      224
  Interface:    -1

Device Found
  type: 05ac 030d
  path: IOService:/IOResources/IOBluetoothHCIController/AppleBroadcomBluetoothHostController/IOBluetoothDevice/IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel/BNBMouseDevice
  serial_number: **-**-**-**-**-**
  Manufacturer: Apple
  Release:      306
  Interface:    -1

...
```